# Suggestions for Exploratory Data Analysis for high-dimensional regression data?

Tags: regression, logistic, feature-selection, exploratory-data-analysis, high-dimensional

I have a moderately high-dim dataset (around 20 predictors) that I plan to analyse using Bayesian variable selection techniques. This will be a logistic regression analysis since the output is a classification. I'm kinda new to this and was looking for some EDA suggestions before I start writing the variable selection methods.